# Lost my WiFi connection when going from U13 to U14

Tags: wireless

Using dual operating systems, Win 7 and Ubuntu 13.10. Installed Ubuntu 14.4 and lost my ability to connect to WiFi. Win 7 works fine, no problem on automatic connection. Ubuntu 14.4 installed nicely EXCEPT does not automatically connect. Yes, I have read the help section on WiFi connection. Why can I connect with Win 7 and Ubuntu 13, but no longer with Ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 0):

sure earlier distro linux was using a non open source driver. once you have upgraded from 13 to 14, you have lost it. i hardly recommend you to take a look at any fork of ubuntu or debian distro, like Elementary http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=elementary or even better, Bodhi Linux http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=bodhi , both of them are heavy based on ubuntu.